# Modifying existing edit tool to make new tool using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, editing

I want to create versions of the edit tools that will add a parallel, offset segment each time I add a segment regularly. Is it possible to put a wrapper around the existing tools? Or otherwise add to their functionality?

e.g. Using the sketch tool I click twice on the screen. Code that I write would add a perpendicular segment on the front of a specified length and a parallel segment. I add another segment and it adds another parallel segment. I add a curve and it adds a parallel curve.

Do I have to make the tools from scratch or can I use the existing ones to add the segments and just tack on code to add the extra segments? Recreating the sketch tool wouldn't be so bad but the other tools are more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be done with an [Editor Extension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002nq000000).  When IEditEvents.OnSketchFinished fires, depending on what the currenttask is modify the sketch by adding parallel segments etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that copy parallel does not work for you.

Understand that you would first digitize one side, then, when you are done select them all and copy parallel.

Unless I am missing something in your question.